# Is Breeze worth the dependency?

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I am programming a machine learning algorithm in Scala. For that one I don't think I will need matrices, but I will need vectors. However, the vectors won't even need a dot product, but just element-wise operations. I see two options:

- use a linear algebra library like [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze)
- implement my vectors as Scala collections like `List` or `Vector` and work on them in a functional manner

The advantage of using a linear algebra library might mean less programming for me... will it though, considering learning? I already started learning and using it and it seems not that straight forward (documentation is so-so). (Another) disadvantage is having a extra dependency. I don't have much experience in writing my own projects (so far I programmed in the job, where libraries usage was dictated).

So, is a linear algebra library - e.g. Breeze - worth the learning and dependency compared to programming needed functionality myself, in my particular case?

Comment: I'd say yes. Though poorly documented, the API for breeze is actually pretty nice and fairly straightforward (at least the basic stuff -- which is all you appear to need.) You don't want use scala `Vector` or `List` for this sort of thing as the standard Scala collections are not specialized and therefore any primitive numeric types you put into them are going to be auto-boxed, costing you memory and cpu cycles.

Comment: @JasonLenderman: Can you elaborate? I know what auto-boxing is, but what do you mean by primitive types here? I am using the Scala `Double` and Scala `Int` (`Integer` seems to be the Java integer). As far as I understand they are not exactly primitives and I wasn't aware that Scala has primitives in the Java sense of `int` vs `Integer` or `double` vs `Double`.

Comment: The Scala types that correspond to Java's primitive types, e.g. `Double`, `Int`, etc. are represented internally as primitive types (i.e. no wrapping) in Scala for efficiency. But if you put them in a Scala collection then they will be wrapped into an object. If you're going to write you're own vector class, you want to represent it internally as an `Array[Double]`.

Comment: @JasonLenderman: Are the Scala types represented internally by **Java** primitive types? So far I have always been using Scala Double and Scala Int and not any primitives. Is this costing me performance?

Comment: I'm not gonna weigh in on whether or not you should use Breeze, since I am biased. Scala Double/Int etc are always primitives except in generics that have not been specialized. I have been very, very careful in Breeze to avoid boxing. It's hard to get speed and an API like Breeze's, and I think I succeeded. re: docs, please, anytime you're confused, please say something or (even better) update the docs!

Comment: @Make42, compiler magic makes them appear to be objects, but Scala's `Double`, `Int`, `Char`, `Boolean`, `Byte` really just compile down to the corresponding Java primitive types, so there is no performance hit in using them. But as @dlwh mentioned, you need to be careful using them in situations where you have type parameters which are not specialized, e.g. the standard Scala collections, because this will caused them to be boxed/unboxed.

Comment: @JasonLenderman: If these Scala `Double`, `Int` etc. are compiled to Java primitives `double`, `int`, etc., why would there be any boxing within the collections? To what? Java `Double`, `Integer` etc.?

Comment: @Make42, take a look at this link: http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/ for more info.